# How to collapse TitledPane programmatically in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Does anyone know how to programmatically collapse a TitledPane in JavaFX?  I know the methods setExpanded and setCollapsible are available but it only enables the property.  I want to collapse the pane without any mouse interaction.

```
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    });

    TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane();
    titledPane.setAnimated(true);
    titledPane.setText("This is a test");
    titledPane.setContent(btn);
    titledPane.setExpanded(true);

    Accordion accordion = new Accordion();
    accordion.getPanes().add(titledPane);

    Button show = new Button("Expand");
    show.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        accordion.setExpandedPane(titledPane); // Expanded Pane works!
    });

    Button hide = new Button("Collapse");
    hide.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        //???
    });

    HBox layout = new HBox(10);
    layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: cornsilk; -fx-padding: 10;");
    layout.getChildren().addAll(show, hide, accordion);
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 320, 240);
    scene.setFill(Color.GHOSTWHITE);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Here is the result I am looking for

Comment: Can you show what you tried with `TitledPane.setExpanded(...);` That should do what you want.

Comment: @James_D, Thanks for responding.`TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane();
        titledPane.setAnimated(true);
        titledPane.setText("This is a test");
        titledPane.setContent(btn);
        titledPane.setExpanded(true);
        titledPane.setCollapsible(true);
        Accordion accordion = new Accordion();
        accordion.getPanes().add(titledPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 80, 180);
        scene.setFill(Color.GHOSTWHITE);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Group root1 = (Group)scene.getRoot();
        root1.getChildren().add(accordion);`

Comment: My first time responding so bear with me on the formatting :)

Comment: And it doesn't appear expanded? (BTW, edit your question with the code, instead of putting it in the comment.)

Comment: @James_D, first I tried titledPane.setExpanded(true) and debugged the project but it still didn't show up in the expanded state.  I still had to click to get it to expand.

Comment: Create a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating the issue, and edit your question to show the code. This works for me. (The default is to start expanded anyway, I think.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since only one `TitledPane` in the same `Accordion` can be expanded at any time, the `Accordion` (to some extent) manages the expanded state of any `TitledPane`s it contains.

You can do

```
accordion.setExpandedPane(titledPane);
```

to get the accordion to expand `titledPane`.

Calling `titledPane.setExpanded(true);` also works, but only if you invoke this after the window has been shown (for reasons I don't fully understand).

Comment: Thanks @James_D, that worked!  If I wanted to collapse the titledPane in code, how could I achieve this?  I do not see a function to collapse the titledPane.  I will modify my example.

Comment: Once the stage is showing you can just do `titledPane.setExpanded(false);`, or you can do `accordion.setExpandedPane(null);`

Comment: titledPane.setExpanded(true); is not working even after the window (Dialog) is shown.  Even if I make sure the property changes by setting it false first. (JavaFX  12)